# Получить имя цвета по hex или rgb коду в java

Tags: java, color, hex, rgb

Задача следующая: есть строка содержащая код цвета, например #75CD5C. Есть html названия цветов(всего примерно 147 цветов) необходимо получая hex код вывести название цвета в html. Задача не сложная, если цвета совпадают. Но вот если цвет промежуточный, надо вывести то название, к которому он ближе всего. Примерно так: приходит код #F08080 этот цвет соответствует html цвету LightCoral. Но вот если приходит код #F08081 то названия у такого цвета нет в html, хотя понятно, что он будет близок к предыдущему цвету.
Подскажите, как можно это все реализовать программно? Может есть уже готовые библиотеки? Буду рад любым советам и подсказкам

Comment: ближе визуально или по rgb ? это не одно и тоже, цвет - не тривиалная материя..

Comment: Визуально. Но пока нет идей как это сделать.